# How to keep Vim's visual selection with custom movement?

Tags: vim

I have some movement utilities in my vim rc which helps me navigate in the file faster, but I would also like to use them when visual selecting. 
Here is the current key binding that I have:
in ~/.vimrc

```
nnoremap <C-h> b
nnoremap <C-l> w
nnoremap <C-j> 5j
nnoremap <C-k> 5k
nnoremap <Tab> :call Tab() <CR>

function! Tab()
    let col = col(".")
    let line = line(".")
        normal! %
    if (col == col(".") && line == line("."))
        normal! $
    endif
endfunction
```

Is there a way to visual select with these utilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add corresponding visual mode mappings:

```
vnoremap <C-h> b
vnoremap <C-l> w
vnoremap <C-j> 5j
vnoremap <C-k> 5k
vnoremap <Tab> :<c-u>call Tab()<CR>gv
```

Note that some extra work is needed for the `<Tab>` mapping in visual mode. Namely, clear the automatic visual boundary markers when entering :-command mode, then re-select the visual area after the function has been called.

Comment: `:%s/vnore/xnore`